# Pointers to an array using functions

Tags: c, arrays, swap

Here's my code:

```
void bubbleSortInventory(article inventory[], int noOfArticles){
    int newn;

    int check = 0;

    while(check != 0){
        newn = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= noOfArticles-1;i++){
            if(inventory[i-1].id>inventory[i].id){
                swap(&inventory[i-1].id,&inventory[i].id);
                newn = i;
            }
        }//end for-loop
        check = newn;
    }
}
```

and the swap function:

```
void swap(int *number1, int *number2){
    int temporaryHolder;

    temporaryHolder = *number1;
    *number1 = *number2;
    *number2 = temporaryHolder;
}
```

Now to the problem, when I print out the array inventory it does not seem to be sorted

Anyone know what I have done wrong?

Solved, thanks

Comment: Format your code. Capitalize words like "I". Don't leave off apostrophes. People will spend more time looking at your questions if you'll spend more time posting them correctly.

Comment: Assuming you fix the initial value of your check condition...are you trying to swap the IDs of your articles, or swap whole articles? Shouldn't your swap function signature be `swap(article *article1, article *article2)`?

Comment: @ludde If an answer solves your problem please to be sure to accept it (Green Check-Mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function assigns `0` to `check`...

```
int check = 0;
```

...and the following condition is `check != 0`...

```
while(check != 0) {
    // ...
}
```

...which won't ever pass the condition.

Your `while() {}` loop will never execute, so it won't ever modify the array passed in.

Comment: Thank you, got tunnel vision on this one, didnt notice that, works perfectly now.